# Variable Selection One by One vs Simultaneously

Tags: regression, model-selection, multiple-regression, feature-selection, lasso

The high dimensional variable selection problem is really popular now. But I have a question: If I do simple linear regression regressing one response variable on 1 covariate at a time first and then control the FDR to select the significant feature variables, what's the disadvantage of this comparing to the lasso or group lasso algorithm, which choose the feature variables simultaneously?

Basically the question could be reduced to **what's the difference between regressing one response variable on multiple covariates vs on 1 covariate at a time?**

Comment: I agree with gung. Also note that model discussion has been discussed a lot lately here, that might help you further. As for your approach, one problem are correlated predictors or predictors that are only influential after controlling for others.

Comment: (+1) @gung for the gentle approach. Do note that of the 9 questions, only 4 have received answers (and two others have been closed). I still suspect you are correct in that the OP is simply unfamiliar with this aspect of the interface.

Comment: I see two *very different* questions here. Your second question is handled in any competent text on linear regression theory, but it is not the same as you first question.

Comment: @gung Thanks. I modified the questions. and I also choose the correct answers for the previous questions. I am sorry that I did not do that since I do not know that.

Comment: The main difference is your multiple t-testing/FDR approach fails to consider the significance of a feature conditional on other features being in the model. LASSO (via the LARS/forward stagewise algorithm) is adding a little bit of each predictor until another predictor is equally correlated with the residuals. The solution path implicitly considers all features when determining the model.

Answer (score 1):

Before going to the specifics of the method, first we need to understand the two classes of feature selection: 
1. **Univariate:** where we consider the input features one by one.
2. **Multivariate:** where we consider a group of variables together.

In many cases univariate feature selection can produce good enough results and like all things in machine learning "there is no free lunch" kicks in and you have to decide everything based on data.

For example, in the chessboard problem (often also known as XOR problem) in feature selection as shown in figure below. Both X and Y would not be able to distinguish the two classes red and black; while both of them taken together can distinguish the two.

[image: Chessboard problem in feature selection]

This video from over 10 years before explains this should be give a good introduction 
http://www.quizover.com/oer/course/introduction-to-feature-select-by-isabelle-gu-videolectures-net
Including this article  http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/guyon03a/guyon03a.pdf by the presenter herself.